# Delete Doc files and keep Docx files

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to delete `.doc` files in a folder that also contains `.docx` files too.

This is my attempt so far:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(Path, "*.doc", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

foreach (string f in files)
{
    File.Delete(f);
}
```

It deletes word documents with extensions of `.doc` and `.docx`.
I want to delete `.doc` files only and keep `.docx` files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MSDN documentation for the [Directory.GetFiles Method (String, String, SearchOption)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316(v=vs.110).aspx) includes this note:

> When you use the asterisk wildcard character in a *searchPattern* such
>   as "*.txt", the number of characters in the specified extension
>   affects the search as follows:
>
> •If the specified extension is exactly three characters long, the
>   method returns files with extensions that begin with the specified
>   extension. For example, "*.xls" returns both "book.xls" and
>   "book.xlsx".
>
> •In all other cases, the method returns files that exactly match the
>   specified extension. For example, "*.ai" returns "file.ai" but not
>   "file.aif".
>
> When you use the question mark wildcard character, this method returns
>   only files that match the specified file extension. For example, given
>   two files, "file1.txt" and "file1.txtother", in a directory, a search
>   pattern of "file?.txt" returns just the first file, whereas a search
>   pattern of "file*.txt" returns both files.

The easiest way to work around Microsoft being "helpful" in this manner is to filter the results of the `Directory.GetFiles` call:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(filesPath, "*.doc", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

foreach (string f in files.Where(f => Path.GetExtension(f) == ".doc"))
{
    File.Delete(f);
}
```

I renamed your `Path` variable because it clashes with the `System.IO.Path` class which holds the static `GetExtension` method. As a general rule of thumb, giving variables the same name as existing classes is a bad habit.

Answer (score 2):

Filter the results for the exact extension you are after.

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(Path, "*.doc", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
foreach (string f in files.Where(f => String.Compare(".doc", f.Extension, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0))
{
    File.Delete(f);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
DirectoryInfo Dir = new DirectoryInfo(path);


foreach (FileInfo file in Dir.GetFiles())
{

    //Code
}
```

as you can access the file extension with

```
file.Extension
```

like this. I guess that's safer to use

Comment: The above is a good way of doing this, just an idea, but you may want to also account for the case of the filetype, ie upper/lower.

Comment: So use String.ToLower()

Answer (score 1):

That problem occurs because Windows ignores any part of a file extension that is longer than 3 characters.

Changing your code to this will solve it:

```
var files = Directory
   .GetFiles(Path, "*.doc", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
   .Where(w => w.ToLowerInvariant().EndsWith(".doc"));
```

Comment: This answer worked for me

Comment: The statement "That problem occurs because Windows ignores any part of a file extension that is longer than 3 characters." is **wrong**. The OP has run into a place where Microsoft tried to be "helpful" and ended up being confusing instead. See the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: When you say: "tried to be "helpful"" - do you mean it ignored any part of the file extension that was longer than 3 digits? It's seems to me that "Ignores digits" and "being helpful" is a distinction without a difference. :)

Comment: @Ulric: no, by 'tried to be "helpful"' I meant that, "**in the specific case of a three-letter file extension** it returns files with extensions beginning with those three characters". IIRC, Microsoft threw this hack in when Office 2007 came out, so that file dialogs hardcoded with (e.g.) "*.ppt" would show all PowerPoint documents (whether using the .ppt or .pptx extensions). If you pass a wildcard with fewer or more than three characters in the extension, `Directory.GetFiles` works the way you'd expect (returning only those files matching the extension).

Comment: _"I meant that, "in the specific case of a three-letter file extension it returns files with extensions beginning with those three characters"."_  ...which involves ignoring any part of the file extension that was longer than 3 digits. As I said: a distinction without a difference.

Answer (score 1):

You can get first extension, put a check for .doc file. then call delete function.

```
string extension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(@"c:\yourfile.docx");
if(extension != ".docx")
{
   //DELETE FILE HERE
}
```

Comment: Would this not delete any file that is not equal to .docx passed into GetExtension?  Even if the file is .DOCX? it will still be deleted

Comment: There we placed a checkl if(extension != ".docx") . So you will only get those files where extension NOT EQUAL TO (!=) '.docx'

Answer (score 1):

```
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(Path, "*.doc", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        foreach (string f in files.Where(f => !f.EndsWith(".docx")))
        {
            File.Delete(f);
        }
```

Microsoft provides examples of this problem in their overview of the method DirectoryInfo.GetFiles Method (String, SearchOption) (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143327(v=vs.110).aspx). They state:

> The following list shows the behavior of different lengths for the searchPattern parameter:

- "*.abc" returns files having an extension
  of.abc,.abcd,.abcde,.abcdef, and so on.
- "*.abcd" returns only files having an extension of.abcd.
- "*.abcde" returns only files having an extension of .abcde.
- "*.abcdef" returns only files having an extension of .abcdef.

You need to filter the result set of Directory.GetFiles so that you're only operating on the files that you want.